# Wrong week number displaying on SSRS report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have in the query and running on sql 2008 r2

```
datepart(ww, CreatedOn) as WeekYear
```

which for Jan 1 2015 returns as week 1.  Perfect.  When using the same query in report designer and running the report, SSRS seems to be converting it to week 53.  Jan 2 2015 is fine as week 1, just the Jan 1 are changing.  For that field im only using the value from the query, I'm not asking SSRS to do any converting of values.  Is this just a quirk of SSRS?

Comment: Sounds like a timezone issue. January 1, 2015 localized to a timezone 1 hour east of GMT becomes December 31, 2014 23:00 UTC. What timezone is your report server using?

Comment: @JC. I thougth so to but the CreatedOn is `2015-01-01 22:08:38.000` and the UTCTOCST is `2015-01-01 16:08:38.000`

Comment: Is your report server in a timezone west of you?

Comment: @JC.No, the query returns the correct result, it's what happends in SSRS that changes the week number.

Comment: Try printing the full date and time on the report and see what SSRS thinks it is.

Comment: Oh wait. This may be a red herring, sorry. Moving this to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The week of year function of `DatePart` depends on the optional `FirstWeekOfYearValue` argument. The argument is supposed to default to `FirstWeekOfYear.Jan1` which means the week that contains Jan. 1 is week 1. It might not be doing so.

Try this: `DatePart(ww, CreatedOn, 1, 1)`.

And if that doesn't work, try hard-coding the date for a sanity check:

Try this: `DatePart(ww, DateSerial(2015,1,1), 1, 1)`.

If the hard-coded date works and your date field does not, then there's definitely something going on with timezones.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20ee97hz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and time, I'll check it out in the morning